# awk join two files and delete same columns

Tags: awk

I have two files, the first file contain:

```
  rs1210110 1:14096821  C   ENSG00000116731 ENST00000505823 Transcript 
  rs1210110 1:14096821  C   ENSG00000116731 ENST00000491815 Transcript  
  rs1210110 1:14096821  C   ENSG00000116731 ENST00000343137 Transcript
  rs2746462 2:17380497  T   ENSG00000117118 ENST00000485515 Transcript
  rs2746462 2:17380497  T   ENSG00000117118 ENST00000375499 Transcript
  rs3219489 2:45797505  G   ENSG00000132781 ENST00000525160 Transcript
```

second file contain:

```
chr1    14096821    rs1210110   T   C   100.00  PASS    DP=89
chr2    17380497    rs2746462   G   T   100.00  PASS    DP=158
```

I would like to join it to one file, where will be

```
    chr1 14096821 rs1210110 T C 100.00 PASS DP=89  ENSG00000116731  ENST00000505823 Transcript  
    chr1 14096821 rs1210110 T C 100.00 PASS DP=89  ENSG00000116731  ENST00000491815 Transcript
    chr1 14096821 rs1210110 T C 100.00 PASS DP=89  ENSG00000116731  ENST00000343137 Transcript
    chr2 17380497 rs2746462 G T 100.00 PASS DP=158 ENSG00000117118  ENST00000485515 Transcript
    chr2 17380497 rs2746462 G T 100.00 PASS DP=158 ENSG00000117118  ENST00000375499 Transcript
    chr2 17380497 rs2746462 G G 100.00 PASS DP=158 ENSG00000132781  ENST00000525160 Transcript
```

Than, second file contain at third column rs code, which is same at first file at first column. But one row from the second file could have more rows from the first file, but with same rs code. And third column from first file will be in the output at 5th column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All done in `awk`

```
cat f1
rs1210110 1:14096821  C   ENSG00000116731 ENST00000505823 Transcript
rs1210110 1:14096821  C   ENSG00000116731 ENST00000491815 Transcript
rs1210110 1:14096821  C   ENSG00000116731 ENST00000343137 Transcript
rs2746462 2:17380497  T   ENSG00000117118 ENST00000485515 Transcript
rs2746462 2:17380497  T   ENSG00000117118 ENST00000375499 Transcript
rs3219489 2:45797505  G   ENSG00000132781 ENST00000525160 Transcript
```

```
cat f2
chr1    14096821    rs1210110   T   C   100.00  PASS    DP=89
chr2    17380497    rs2746462   G   T   100.00  PASS    DP=158
```

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$2]=$0;next} {split($2,b,":");print a[b[2]],$4,$5,$6 }' OFS="\t" f2 f1
chr1    14096821    rs1210110   T   C   100.00  PASS    DP=89   ENSG00000116731 ENST00000505823 Transcript
chr1    14096821    rs1210110   T   C   100.00  PASS    DP=89   ENSG00000116731 ENST00000491815 Transcript
chr1    14096821    rs1210110   T   C   100.00  PASS    DP=89   ENSG00000116731 ENST00000343137 Transcript
chr2    17380497    rs2746462   G   T   100.00  PASS    DP=158  ENSG00000117118 ENST00000485515 Transcript
chr2    17380497    rs2746462   G   T   100.00  PASS    DP=158  ENSG00000117118 ENST00000375499 Transcript
        ENSG00000132781 ENST00000525160 Transcript
```

Last line did not have a match, so it will be printed out with no information in front.  This can be removed if needed.

---

A some different approach with `awk`

```
awk -F"[ \t:]*" 'FNR==NR {a[$2]=$0;next} {print a[$3],$5,$6,$7 }' OFS="\t" f2 f1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`join`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/join-invocation.html#join-invocation) to join and `awk` to reorder.

```
$ cat f1
rs1210110 1:14096821  C   ENSG00000116731 ENST00000505823 Transcript 
rs1210110 1:14096821  C   ENSG00000116731 ENST00000491815 Transcript  
rs1210110 1:14096821  C   ENSG00000116731 ENST00000343137 Transcript
rs2746462 2:17380497  T   ENSG00000117118 ENST00000485515 Transcript
rs2746462 2:17380497  T   ENSG00000117118 ENST00000375499 Transcript
rs3219489 2:45797505  G   ENSG00000132781 ENST00000525160 Transcript
$ cat f2
chr1    14096821    rs1210110   T   C   100.00  PASS    DP=89
chr2    17380497    rs2746462   G   T   100.00  PASS    DP=158
$ join -1 1 -2 3 f1 f2 | awk '{print $7, $8, $1, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $4, $5, $6}'
chr1 14096821 rs1210110 T C 100.00 PASS DP=89 ENSG00000116731 ENST00000505823 Transcript
chr1 14096821 rs1210110 T C 100.00 PASS DP=89 ENSG00000116731 ENST00000491815 Transcript
chr1 14096821 rs1210110 T C 100.00 PASS DP=89 ENSG00000116731 ENST00000343137 Transcript
chr2 17380497 rs2746462 G T 100.00 PASS DP=158 ENSG00000117118 ENST00000485515 Transcript
chr2 17380497 rs2746462 G T 100.00 PASS DP=158 ENSG00000117118 ENST00000375499 Transcript
```